# SDK2: Using updateSettings()

Tags: javascript, extjs4, rally

I'm trying to save settings for my app.  It looks like it should be simple, but this does not seem to work:

```
      Ext.define('MyApp', {
          extend: 'Rally.app.App',
          componentCls: 'app',

          ...

          launch: function() {
                var settings = this.settings;

                console.log('settings', settings);

                if (!settings.count) {
                    settings.count = 1;
                } else {
                    settings.count++;
                }

                this.updateSettingsValues(settings);

                    ... rest of App ...
            }
```

Always show settings as "count: 1", never increments, even as I reload multiple times.  I have tried this both in and outside of Rally.  I am using SDK 2.0p5.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I took a look at the source and I figured it out...need to pass a "options" object with "settings" as a subobject.  This is technically in the doc, but because it was not explained I just did what looked obvious.  I think the doc needs to be update to make this more clear, it also does not speak about the completion functions you can pass in with options...

```
      launch: function() {
            var settings = this.settings;
            var options = { settings: settings };

            console.log('settings', settings);

            if (!settings.count) {
                settings.count = 1;
            } else {
                settings.count++;
            }

            this.updateSettingsValues(options);

                ... rest of App ...
        }
```

Comment: We're actually in the process of making settings much easier to use in apps right now.  We'll make sure to update the doc and release an example showing how to use them.